# How to see all my changes before pushing my changes into git under PhpStorm?

Tags: git, phpstorm

Using phpstorm 2021.1.4 if there is a way before pushing my changes into git to check all changes in all files,
like I have on gitlab, where I can see old/modified lines like in github?
I would like to use such functionality under phpstorm, not some ubuntu external apps, as I would like to see these changes in currect phpstorm style...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: View | Tool Windows | Git

Comment: Yes, I see “Default Changelist” with all files I see with git status command.
Settings of my project are such as some files under “public/” are autoupdated  and are shows by git status command, but I do not need to commit them.
Can I add some options to  “Default Changelist”  not to see some files in it (only in this Changelist) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add these files that are autoupdated to .gitignore and only files you edit yourself will be present in changelist.